# CORBA: Trouble while attempting to configure and run OpenORB

Tags: java, configuration, corba, openorb

I am writing a simulator for a CORBA client, that is I am simulating a CORBA server.

A requirement of the CORBA server is that it register a certain object with the CORBA NameService.

I have somehow stumbled across OpenORB.

I have downloaded all its binary zip archives and have extracted them all to a single directory- `%TCOO_HOME%`. I run the NameService via the `ins.bat` script in the `%TCOO_HOME%\NamingService\bin` directory.

I manage to run the NameService.

If I edit the `ins.bat` file and add to `%JAVA% -Xbootclasspath/p:%BOOTCLASSPATH% -Dopenorb.home.path=%TCOO_HOME% -jar %TCOO_HOME%\tools\lib\launcher.jar org.openorb.ins.Server %*` command the flags: `-u -e --debug debug` I can even see the following printed out:

```
[main] [DEBUG] (ins.svc): Trying to bind: 'COS/NameService/NamingContextExt' ( NoNS = true )
[main] [INFO ] (ins.svc): NameService=corbaloc:iiop:1.2@localhost:683/NameService
```

If I edit the `default.xml` configuration file in `%TCOO_HOME%\OpenORB\config` and change the port to say 684 in the following manner:

```
<profile name="DefaultCorbalocService">
    <description>
    This profile loads the CorbalocService module, and sets the port
    number in iiop to 683, the default port.
    </description>

    <import module="CorbalocService" />
    <import module="iiop" >
      <property name="port" value="684" />
    </import>
</profile>
```

No change occurs to the output of the ins.bat file - in other words the configuration change is not discerned by the ins.

1. Help would be highly appreciated
2. A recommendation of a different, perhaps more easily configurable, ORB might also be nice

A heart felt thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have finally done it...

I can only answer my first question and not the second.

I have run: `ins -ORBopenorb.home=%TCOO_HOME%\home`
(remember I have added the following flags to `ins.bat`: `-u -e --debug debug`)

I have copied the following files to `%TCOO_HOME%\home`:

1. default.xml
2. OpenORB.xml
3. orb.properties
4. pss.xml

and the output contains the following as expected:

```
[main] [DEBUG] (ins.svc): Trying to bind: 'COS/NameService/NamingContextExt' ( NoNS = true )
[main] [INFO ] (ins.svc): NameService=corbaloc:iiop:1.2@localhost:684/NameService
```

**EDIT:**

In case you don't wish to use the -e flag you should edit the default profile in the OpenORB.xml as such:

```
<profile name="default" xlink:href="${openorb.home}config/default.xml#default">
    <description>
        The default profile loads the POA, iiop and some basic initial references.
    </description>      

    <import xlink:href="${openorb.home}config/default.xml#iiop">
        <property name="port" value="684"/>
    </import>       
</profile>
```